# Virtualizing physical Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a HDD that seves as dead data archive. I want to virtualize the HDD in XenServer in atempt of evade some problems (like losing the HDD itself).

I tried the VMconverter from VMware (to futher convert the VM to XenServer) but it doesn't worked quite well. The VM's Windows has an error (0xc00002e1) that could only be fixed by a clean reinstall.

Has anyone an advice or solution to convert my HDD to one of these servers?

Comment: What hypervisor are you converting it for? XenServer or vSphere or Hyper-V?

Comment: I tried to vSphere (and ESXI) v. 5.1.0. BUT, I tried vSphere 'cause i didn't found a way to virtualize directly to XenServer (wich is what I use).

Comment: Did you try the XenServer conversion tools? - https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenserver/tools/conversion.html

Comment: No, I didn't know that this existed. I give it a try and will feedback

Comment: @joeqwerty none of the versions of XenConverter install on my Win. Server